# How do I get python lxml to find this element?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

Given a XML file of this structure:

```
<log>
    <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
        <System>
            <EventID>1</EventID> # if this is 1
        </System>
        <EventData>
            <Data Name="CommandLine">C:\Windows\system32\wbem\unsecapp.exe -Embedding</Data> # then I want this value
        </EventData>
    </Event>
  <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
        <System>
            <EventID>2</EventID>
        </System>
        <EventData>
            <Data Name="CommandLine">C:\Windows\system32\wbem\unsecapp.exe -Embedding</Data>
        </EventData>
    </Event>
</log>
```

I want to check all `<Event>` if the `<EventID>` = 1 and then use the value of `<Data Name='CommandLine'>`

Using this code

```
from lxml import etree as ET

with open(log_file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:                                                                     
    log_content = file.read()   
root = ET.fromstring(log_content)

ns = {'ns' : 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'}

root.xpath("//ns:Event[System/EventID='1']/EventData/Data[@Name='CommandLine']", namespaces=ns)
```

finds nothing.

I tried the same xpath query `//Event[System/EventID='1']/EventData/Data[@Name='CommandLine']` in an online xpath tool with the same xml and it works as intended.

I can't figure out the problem, any ideas?

Comment: may be if you printed the command lines that would help
```
command_lines = root.xpath(...)\n
for command_line in command_lines:\n
    print(command_line.text)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A default namespace on an element applies to its descendant elements too, so change

`//ns:Event[System/EventID='1']/EventData/Data[@Name='CommandLine']`

to

`//ns:Event[ns:System/ns:EventID='1']/ns:EventData/ns:Data[@Name='CommandLine']`

Answer (score 2):

Solution with your xpath in lxml to search `text()`:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

xml = '''
<log>
    <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
        <System>
            <EventID>1</EventID>
        </System>
        <EventData>
            <Data Name="CommandLine">C:/Windows/system32/wbem/unsecapp.exe -Embedding1</Data>
        </EventData>
    </Event>
  <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
        <System>
            <EventID>2</EventID>
        </System>
        <EventData>
            <Data Name="CommandLine">C:/Windows/system32/wbem/unsecapp.exe -Embedding2</Data>
        </EventData>
    </Event>
</log>'''


root = ET.fromstring(xml)
nsmap = {'ns':'http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event'}

print(root.xpath('''//ns:Event[ns:System/ns:EventID='1']/ns:EventData/ns:Data[@Name='CommandLine']/text()''', namespaces=nsmap)[0])
```

Output:

```
C:/Windows/system32/wbem/unsecapp.exe -Embedding1
```